# Create custom controls in asp mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, user-controls, razor

I have to create custom controls in ASP.NET MVC 3. Controls like customized buttons which I will put in DLL and reuse in any project.

Do you know a good way or maybe you can give me a good tutorial to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, WebControls are for Web Forms. In asp.net mvc anything view related(html, javascript, css) is decoupled from the controller. The best you can do is to have helpers which are simply extension methods. But something similar to the webcontrols is specific to web forms only.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6367440/394028) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224378/Custom-Controls-for-MVC3) should give you an idea

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but isn't there a solution by creating classes which inherit from "System.Web.UI.WebControls"

Comment: As stated in the other answers, the web controls are of webform. If you look around you will find article on how to have mvc running webcontrols, but I will suggest you to not go down that road. use the article I linked to you as a starter

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Partial Views to re-use code.

http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/